# Limit to multiple countries using GooglePlacesAutocomplete with react-native

Tags: react-native, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete, country-codes

I have seen a few posts explaining how to set multiple countries for google places autocomplete in javascript/react as so:
`componentRestrictions: {country: ["gb", "fr"]}`

but for react-native GooglePlacesAutocomplete, the advice is to put a components option within query. Unsure if here we can pass multiple countries... have tried and failed to pass an array here as looks like it needs to just be a string containing one country code. Would appreciate any help...

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder={placeholder}
        listViewDisplayed={true}
        fetchDetails={true}
        textInputProps={{
          borderColor: color,
          fontSize: 18,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 4,
          flex: 1,
          padding: 7
        }}
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
          console.log(data, details)
        }}
        query={{
          key: googleApiKey,
          language: "en",
          components: "country:gb",
          types: types ? types : null
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component restrictions like so `components: "country:gb|country:us"`

See full code example below

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder={placeholder}
            listViewDisplayed={true}
            fetchDetails={true}
            textInputProps={{
              borderColor: color,
              fontSize: 18,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 4,
              flex: 1,
              padding: 7
            }}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              console.log(data, details)
            }}
            query={{
              key: googleApiKey,
              language: "en",
              components: "country:gb|country:us",
              types: types ? types : null
            }}
          />
```

Comment: @Emma you should select this as an accepted answer if it worked out for you.